# Magento increases image sizes on the front end

Tags: magento

I've noticed that images being served to the front end are bigger than the image is on the server.  From what I can tell,  Magento runs the images through some filter that does things like adds watermarks, adjusts colors, etc.  Is there a way to disable this feature?

edit:  Sorry, I should have been more specific.  I'm referring to product images, and actual file sizes,  not height/width.   The file size of the product images being served are bigger than their original files.

Comment: I've also noticed this behavior which strikes me as rather odd. The images have the exact same dimensions but the file size of the one on the front end is about a third larger. Have you found out anything about it?

Comment: Same here. It increases some file sizes by almost 500%. Its really disturbing. I am yet to look into their code though. But its strange.

Answer (score 1):

The catalog/product image tags are defined in Magento's template files.  The image sizes defined will vary, depending on what images you are referring to.

These templates call the images like this:

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/list.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>
```

If notice on the end, there is a resize function that has a set number in there.  This number will tell Magento to automatically resize the image it retrieves to that dimension.  You can pass a height and width to the resize function, like so:

```
..->resize(height, width);
```

As far as I know, there is no configuration setting that will globally disable this resize function.  You would have to override and void the function using a overwritten file or extension. I would recommend just uploading the correct sized images (larger than the minimum sizes seen on the site).  Magento will then properly scale them down without loss of quality.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific.  I'm referring to product images, and actual file sizes,  not height/width.   The file size of the product images being served are bigger than their original files.